# Второй while не работает

Tags: while, php, mysql

Здравствуйте. Сделал два while. Второй while не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
       <?php

        include_once 'inc/db.php';
        $game = new db();
        $id = 1;
        $game_te = $game->game($id);
          while ($rowread = mysqli_fetch_array($game_te))
          {
              ?>

                    <li><a href="<?php echo $site;?>/game.php?id=<?php echo $rowread['id'];?>" id="ahref"> <?php echo $rowread['name'];?>                
     </a></li>
                   <?php } ?>

                                     <?php

      while ($rowread1 = mysqli_fetch_array($game_te))
      {
          ?>

                  <div class="last_head">
      <a  href="<?php echo $site;?>/game.php?id=<?php echo $rowread1['id'];?>">   
    <img src="<?php echo $site;?>/image/game/game_img/<?php echo $rowread1['image'];?>" width="145" height="130" />
      </a>       
    </div>

        <a  href="<?php echo $site;?>/game.php?id=<?php echo $rowread1['id'];?>">
    <?php echo $rowread1['name'];?>
        </a>

      <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Почитайте на досуге http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php (и ваш код будет более понятным).

Comment: Могу сказать, что так нельзя и кинуться ссылкой на аналогичный пример: http://forum.php.su/topic.php?forum=1&topic=5802. Если и правда нужно, как вы написали выше, то попробуйте  собрать сначала все в массив.

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв. Дело в том, что мне нужно вывести сначала название с таблицы в одном цикле, потом во втором вывести изображения с таблицы. Т.е. сначала в одном диве название игр, а в другом диве изображения. @Flur

Comment: Вся проблема в том, что первый цикл уже перебрал все данные и второму ничего не остается. Решение проблемы: выводите все данные одним циклом, а то, что не нужно выводить сразу, можно, к примеру сохранять в массив и потом циклом выводить, где нужно.

Comment: Сделал так. Выводит результат бесконечное число раз ... @Nik555
{
$test = mysqli_fetch_array($game_te);
while ($test1 = $test)
{
////
}
while ($test2 = $test) {
////
}
}

Comment: @fikos, `$test1 = $test` всегда будет возвращать значение `$test`, который наверняка кастуется в `true`, поэтому цикл будет бесконечным.

Comment: А как можно сделать? По комментариям я так понял, @Etki.

Comment: @fikos, я не так имел в виду... вот мой вариант:
while ($rowread = mysqli_fetch_array($game_te)) {
$temp[] = $rowread;
} потом ниже место второго while пишем:
foreach ($rowread in $temp) {...}

Comment: @Etki не будет он бесконечным - MySql однажды прекратит отдавать данные, отсюда и false. Все у ТС нормально в условии.

@Nik555 прав.

Answer (score 1):

А не легче foreach разобрать запрос, а потом вывести то, что нужно?